# Spring security "Authentication failed: password does not match stored value" with DaoAuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on a simple spring project that user spring security to authenticate.
spring-security.xml

```
<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/hellotheme" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/hellobootstrap"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

And spring-database.xml

```
<!-- MySQL data source -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="123456" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>orm/Roles.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>orm/UserRoles.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>orm/Users.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                       org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
                    </prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="userDao" class="com.sample.dao.UserDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="myUserDetailsService" 
            class="com.sample.services.MyUserDetailsService">
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDao" />
</bean>

<!-- MUST have transaction manager, using aop and aspects  -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
    <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
    <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
    <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="userServicePointCut"
    expression="execution(* com.sample.services.*Service.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userServicePointCut" />
</aop:config>
```

When I run and try to login I got the error like this `DaoAuthenticationProvider - Authentication failed: password does not match stored value`.

But the entity I got that have exactly the same info that stored in database. And in my project I'm not use any encoder for password.

I couldn't know what is the stored password, it been protected.

Could anyone help me solve this?

**UPDATE**

Here is the debug log.

```
13:58:09.229 DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - com.sample.entities.Roles{id=1, description=, userRoleses=<uninitialized>, role=ROLE_ADMIN}
13:58:09.231 DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - com.sample.entities.UserRoles{id=1, users=com.sample.entities.Users#1, roles=com.sample.entities.Roles#1}
13:58:09.232 DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - com.sample.entities.Users{id=1, enabled=true, username=admin, userRoleses=[com.sample.entities.UserRoles#1], password=123456}
13:58:09.234 DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - committed JDBC Connection
13:58:09.234 DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - re-enabling autocommit
13:58:09.241 DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.sample.entities.Roles#1], EntityKey[com.sample.entities.UserRoles#1], EntityKey[com.sample.entities.Users#1]],collectionKeys=[CollectionKey[com.sample.entities.Users.userRoleses#1], CollectionKey[com.sample.entities.Roles.userRoleses#1]]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] orphanRemovals=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] collectionQueuedOps=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] after transaction
13:58:09.242 DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Releasing JDBC connection
13:58:09.243 DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Released JDBC connection
14:00:25.469 DEBUG o.s.s.a.d.DaoAuthenticationProvider - Authentication failed: password does not match stored value
14:06:40.843 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
```

**SECOND UPDATE**
MyUserDetailServiceClass

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    Users user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRoleses());
    return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
}

// Convert from user entity to spring security userdetails
private User buildUserForAuthentication(Users user,
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

    return new User(user.getUsername(),
        user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(),
                    true, true, true, authorities);
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRoles> userRoles) {

    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    // Build user's authorities
    for (UserRoles userRole : userRoles) {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRoles().getRole()));
    }

    List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

    return Result;
}
```

Comment: in logging you will see executed hibernate select query, replace question marks with your username and password parameters and try to execute on mysql workbench.

Comment: I did and it return the correct user.

Comment: Are you encoding your passwords, if yes, then you should mention your encoder as well. If not, you should use encoding. BCrypt 11 rounds sounds good enough. Show your myUserDetailsService class.

Comment: @WeareBorg There is no encoding in my current code. But I also tried BCrypt encoder but it shows the same error.

Comment: You cant just squeeze in the encoder and expect it to work, the passwords saved in DB also need to be encoded before saving. Also, like I said, show the class.

Comment: @WeareBorg I know what you said and that exactly what I did. I use `PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String test = encoder.encode("123456");` to show the encode then save it to my DB.

Comment: Ok, so, now in the DB your password is saved as 123456 or the Bcrypt version. Secondly, print the contents Set<UserRoles> userRoles.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on? I'm running into something similar, it's really strange...?